# no video using webex with fedora 22 and firefox

Tags: fedora, video, libraries, dynamic-linking, core-dump

I can connect into a webex presentation on my Fedora 22 x64 workstation with Firefox x64 but I can't see any video. I am using Firefox version 43.0.3 with the icedtea-web plugin version 4.6.2. I have been running through some troubleshooting steps and here is what I see from the .webex folder. At first I did an ldd on all of the libraries:

```
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/atascli.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/atgzip.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/atjpeg.so:
    not a dynamic executable
   /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/atpng.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libatdv.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libAudioEngine.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libcmcrypto_jni.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libdbr.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libgdiplus.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libmmaud.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libmmsvid.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libmsess.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libtpwrap.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libwbxtrace.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/libwelsvp.so:
    not a dynamic executable
    /home/user/.webex/T30_MC/welsdec.so:
    not a dynamic executable
```

Then I ran a few more tests against one of the libraries:

```
./atascli.so 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

ldd ./atascli.so 
not a dynamic executable

file ./atascli.so 
./atascli.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Strange here ^^^ because it says both that its linked and not linked.

```
strace ./atascli.so 
execve("./atascli.so", ["./atascli.so"], [/* 36 vars */]) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x1} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

At this point I am uncertain whether this is truly a linking problem or the webex app is trying to use 32bit libraries. Can anyone help me figure out what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Enabling all the available WebEx features on Linux involves running 32-bit binaries; the "easiest" way of going about this is to run 32-bit Firefox and Java runtime environment (JRE). I got it working as follows:

1. Download [32-bit Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all/) (the version identified as plain "Linux" rather than "Linux 64-bit", in the language of your choice).
2. Download [a 32-bit JRE](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) (the version identified as plain "Linux" rather than "Linux x64"; download the tarball, *not* the RPM).
3. Extract both somewhere convenient, *e.g.* `/opt`.
4. To allow easier upgrades in the future, rename the `firefox` directory (*e.g.* to `firefox-44.0.2`), and add symlinks for Firefox and the JRE: the script I'll include below assumes respectively `webex-firefox` (pointing to `firefox-44.0.2` or whichever version you have) and `jre1.8.0` (pointing to `jre1.8.0_73` or whichever version you have).
5. Link the Java plugin (you'll need to do this every time you upgrade Firefox):

   `ln -sf /opt/jre1.8.0/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so webex-firefox/browser/plugins`
6. Create a launcher script, as follows (I stored it as `~/bin/webex`, `~/bin` being on my `PATH`):

   `#!/bin/sh`

   `JAVA_HOME=/opt/jre1.8.0 /opt/webex-firefox/firefox -P webex -new-instance https://meetings.webex.com`

With all that done, running `webex` will start a new instance of Firefox, with a new profile (it will prompt you to create one the first time, use `webex` as the profile name), and take you to the WebEx meetings page. We're not quite done yet though because you'll need to install a number of 32-bit libraries as well; this can be done using Fedora packages. You'll need at least the following:

```
sudo dnf install alsa-lib.i686 atk.i686 bzip2-libs.i686 cairo.i686 expat.i686 fontconfig.i686 freetype.i686 gdk-pixbuf2.i686 glib2.i686 glibc.i686 graphite2.i686 gtk2.i686 harfbuzz.i686 libdatrie.i686 libdrm.i686 libffi.i686 libgcc.i686 libICE.i686 libpng.i686 libselinux.i686 libSM.i686 libstdc++.i686 libthai.i686 libuuid.i686 libwayland-client.i686 libwayland.i686 libX11.i686 libXau.i686 libxcb.i686 libXcomposite.i686 libXcursor.i686 libXdamage.i686 libXext.i686 libXfixes.i686 libXft.i686 libXi.i686 libXinerama.i686 libXmu.i686 libXrandr.i686 libXrender.i686 libxshmfence.i686 libXt.i686 libXtst.i686 libXv.i686 libXxf86vm.i686 mesa-libEGL.fc23.i686 mesa-libgbm.i686 mesa-libGL.i686 mesa-libglapi.i686 pango.i686 pangox-compat.i686 pcre.i686 pixman.i686 zlib.i686
```

(To work out this list, I looked for ELF binaries in `~/.webex`, and determined which packages provided the required libraries to run them all.)